# Add more products containers on same page when "ADD PRODUCT" is pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner in Flutter need help in adding containers of Product Name, Price and QTY to the same page when "Add Products" in AddPage is pressed it should got to the SalesItem and create the above mentioned containers.
I have written this code but instead of adding on same page it creates another page and so on containing only one product name, price and qty containers...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gradient_app_bar/gradient_app_bar.dart';

class SalesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: GradientAppBar(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.purple]),
        title: Text('Sales'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SalesItem(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class SalesItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Material(
      child:Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
                height: 45,
                width: 198,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[900]),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Product Name',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                          fontSize: 19.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          size: 22,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {}),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
                height: 45,
                width: 80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[900]),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Price',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      fontSize: 19.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 10),
                height: 45,
                width: 83,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[900]),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'QTY',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        letterSpacing: 2.0,
                        fontSize: 19.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12,
                          width: 20,
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                size: 22,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {}),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          AddPage(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AddPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Add Products'),
            color: Colors.amber[700],
            textColor: Colors.black,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SalesItem()),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, thank you for your question! You could store the `salesItems` in a list on the `SalesPage` and instead of navigating to a new page when the add product button is pressed, you could add a new `SalesItem` to this list. I have added a code sample below showing how this could work. You'll notice that the `SalesPage` is now a `StatefulWidget` because we need to call `setState` whenever a sales item is added to the list in order to rebuild the widget and update the User Interface.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SalesPage(),
    );
  }
}

class SalesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SalesPageState createState() => _SalesPageState();
}

class _SalesPageState extends State<SalesPage> {
  final salesItems = <SalesItem>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sales'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...salesItems,
          AddPage(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                salesItems.add(SalesItem());
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SalesItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 5),
                height: 45,
                width: 198,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[900]),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Product Name',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                          fontSize: 19.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          size: 22,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {}),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
                height: 45,
                width: 80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[900]),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Price',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      fontSize: 19.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 10),
                height: 45,
                width: 83,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[900]),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'QTY',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        letterSpacing: 2.0,
                        fontSize: 19.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 12,
                          width: 20,
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                size: 22,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {}),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final void Function() onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Add Products'),
            color: Colors.amber[700],
            textColor: Colors.black,
            onPressed: onPressed,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```